# Java - Are if-statements thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

This might be a stupid question but.. let's assume I have a class ContainerClass, if contains a HashSet that is accessed from several threads that add and **also remove** elements.. In one of these thread, let's call it thread 1, I execute the following code:

```
if(ContainerClass.hashSet.containsKey(keyId))
    int number = ContainerClass.hashSet.get(keyId);
```

Is it guaranteed that by the time the second line is executed, the element with the key keyId is still there? Or could this thread do the check in the if-statement, then be paused, then another thread alters the HashSet, and thread 1 gets a NullPointerException?

Comment: There's no concept of thread-safety for an `if` statement. Do you mean the object that is being used in the `if` statement's condition?

Comment: A race condition can still happen there where the collection is modified before your other thread can get to the next line of an if statement. If statements are not atomic ( I think this is what you are asking in specific )

Comment: Hmm the second paragraph is a description of what I mean. Basically I'm wondering if these two lines of code get are atomic.

Comment: @spacecoyote way ahead of you, nope.

Comment: Well that's scary and will probably give me a headache soon. Anyway if you convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it, thank you.

Comment: Even the individual calls to `containsKey()` and `get()` are not thread-safe unless you're using a [synchronized set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet&28java.util.Set%29).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed.

To make it guaranteed, you'd have to consistently synchronize access to `hashSet` (presumably it's a `java.util.HashMap`) in order to prevent another thread from modifying the map between these operations.

Alternatively, there are `ConcurrentMap` implementations that, unlike `java.util.HashMap` are intended for use by multiple threads. They support an additional set of operations, like `putIfAbsent()` so that you can atomically check and conditionally modify the map.

Even if you simplify your code to eliminate the unnecessary check, it's still not safe to share a `java.util.HashMap` across threads without a memory barrier.  For example, this isn't safe if another thread might modify the map asynchronously:

```
Integer tmp = ContainerClass.hashSet.get(keyId);
if (tmp != null) {
  int number = tmp.intValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erickson. I guess I should accept this for its detailedness and hints.

Answer (score 0):

It's not guaranteed, thread safety refers to an objects data.  If more than 1 thread can modify it at the same time then it is not thread safe.  If you are concerned about performing logic on a shared object then must do the logic inside a locked statement (synchronized).

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety has to do with shared, mutable state.

No one can decide from your snippet.  If it's a class member you might want to guard it.

If it's a local variable, it's thread safe.

You can also make it safer by using a collection from the [concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html)